# Is it possible to limit a choicefield in a form instance in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-models

I have a form which contains a choicefield called level allowing the selection of value between 0-3 who's options I want to "limit" dynamically. Is this possible?

pseudo-code for the view would contain something like this:

```
form = new instance of myform
allowed_level = 2
form.level maximum value =< allowed_level
```

Comment: "sudo" and "pseudo" mean two different things :)

Comment: @moguzalp The "su" command is an abbreviation of  "super user" so "sudo" means "super user do".

Comment: @moguzalp I'm not sure that's relevant :) It's a misunderstanding of the Unix command name.

Comment: sorry, tired and have been typing sudo for command line all day so it just slipped out, call it cross wiring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can dynamically set the validation criteria when creating the form: (beware: this isn't a complete example as I'm not sure of your setup)

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    level = ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, allowed_level=None):
        self.allowed_level = allowed_level
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_level(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['level']
        # Here you can play with what you want to allow
        if level > self.allowed_level:
            raise forms.ValidationError("A problem with level value")
        return data
```

and just use your view normally

```
def my_view(request, ...):
    form = MyForm(allowed_level=2)
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
```